# How can I make it echo 'That's good' and 'Why not?' if 'Yes' and 'No' are selected respectively?

Tags: windows-10, vbscript, dialog

```
MsgBox "Are you fine?", vbYesNo, "Greeting"

K% = MsgBox "Are you fine?", vbYesNo, "Greeting"
Select Case K%
Case vbYes
    WScript.Echo "That's good."
Case vbNo
    WScript.Echo "Why not?"
End Select
```

I use the above script in a .vbs file to bring up a message box with 'Yes' and 'No' buttons. I want it to echo 'That's good' and 'Why not?' if 'Yes' and 'No' are selected respectively. However, it does not work. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things aren't right:

- A variable name cannot contain a `%` sign. Rename it to something else.
- Missing parentheses when calling msgbox: `MsgBox("Are you fine", vbYesNo, "Greeting")`
- The initial messagebox is called twice

Comment: Actually, I googled it for an hour before asking the question here, after which I found the answer at the above link.